# Finad the largest value in one column and repeat that as a new column

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, loops

For each unique `id`, I want to find the `max(G)` and then repeat it in a new column called `G2`.

Is this possible in BASE R?

Here is a toy input and its desired output:

```
INPUT = data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,2), G = 1:5)
#  id G
#1  1 1
#2  1 2
#3  2 3
#4  2 4
#5  2 5
  
DESIRED_OUTPUT = data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,2), G = 1:5, G2 = c(3,3,5,5,5))
#  id G G2
#1  1 1  2
#2  1 2  2
#3  2 3  5
#4  2 4  5
#5  2 5  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `base R`, use `ave`

```
INPUT$G2 <- with(INPUT, ave(G, id, FUN = function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
INPUT %>%
      group_by(id) %>% 
      mutate(G2 = max(G)) %>%
      ungroup
```

Comment: While waiting to accept, can we test if at least 2 unique `id` have a `G2` value that is larger than `1`?

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, you can do `with(INPUT, length(unique(id[G2 > 1])) >=2)`

Comment: @rnorouzian you can use anonymous function call in ave as in updated